# Does the string variable get escape characters during execution?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose a program is in execution and the value of val1:

```
string val1=TextBox1.Text
```

Now suppose the value of TextBox is 'Hello\n\t'

Then, what will be the value inside the val1? Will it take the \n and \t or will it take as new line and tab?

Now, suppose we assign this value to a label on an aspx page, then will the new line and tabs appear or not. And Why is that?

Comment: **Try it and find out!**

Comment: @NachiKetKamat  can you check my answer

Answer (score 2):

No.. the value will be as it was entered in the textbox.

The actual string will be:

```
Hello\\n\\t
```

Comment: +1. @"Hello\n\t" may be more C# representation... And as usual in debug window it will be shown as "Hello\\n\\t".

Answer (score 1):

If a user types `Hello\n\t` into a text box and then you assign that value to variable you'll have the full literal string, exactly as typed.

No conversion of `"\n"` & `"\t"` to `'\n'` & `'\t'` will take place.

Answer (score 1):

While dubugging It will be like this

```
"Hello\\n\\t"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

while the text has found in between '' or "" in visual basic.. will not be considered as concat...